# I'm having issues raising a ValueError if a specific format is not entered

Tags: python, regex

I want to use a function `convert` to validate a string that should be formatted either like `9 AM to 5 PM` or `9:00 AM to 5:00 PM`. If there is no space between the time and AM and PM, or any other character is used, I want to raise a ValueError, which I can then handle elsewhere.

I have this code:

```
import re
import sys

def main():
    try:
        print(convert(input("Hours: ")))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid format. Please use '9:00 AM to 5:00 PM' or '9 AM to 5 PM'.")

def convert(s):
    matches = re.search(r"^([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)? (AM|PM) to ([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)? (AM|PM)$", s)

    hour1 = int(matches.group(1))
    minute1 = int(matches.group(2) or 0)
    hour2 = int(matches.group(4))
    minute2 = int(matches.group(5) or 0)
    am_pm1 = matches.group(3).upper()
    am_pm2 = matches.group(6).upper()

    if matches:
        if hour1 > 12 or hour2 > 12 or minute1 > 59 or minute2 > 59:
            raise ValueError
        if hour1 == 12 and am_pm1 == "AM":
            hour1 = 0
        elif hour1 != 12 and am_pm1 == "PM":
            hour1 += 12
        if hour2 == 12 and am_pm2 == "AM":
            hour2 = 0
        elif hour2 != 12 and am_pm2 == "PM":
            hour2 += 12
    else:
        raise ValueError

    time1 = f"{hour1:02}:{minute1:02}"
    time2 = f"{hour2:02}:{minute2:02}"
    
    return time1 + " to " + time2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I try running the code and give an invalid input without a space - for example, `9AM to 5PM` - I get an `AttributeError` instead of the desired `ValueError`. The message for the `AttributeError` says `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Why does it do that? I think that the `ValueError` should be raised because the regular expression I used checks for that space. Why do I get an `AttributeError` instead?

Comment: You need to check if `matches` is `None` *before* you assume `matches.group` exists.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: if there is no space between the time and AM and PM (eg. 9AM), or any other character is used, i want to raise a ValueError

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain exactly what happens when the code runs, show some examples that fail (and give error messages or output) show some examples that do what you want. Explain what debugging you have already tried and what you learned.

Comment: The comment you added just repeats text in the question. It does not give the information that Michael requested.

Comment: You formatted the last paragraph as code so that I oversaw it. @chepner answered this already.

Comment: I edited the question to show how to incorporate information that comments ask for while still writing a clear, *direct* question. Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**, despite how the comments might look. This is just for reference for asking future questions. As a side note, I think this is really just a typo (simple logical error) rather than a duplicate question. Please carefully think about the logic of the code. **What needs to happen first** - checking whether the regex matched, or parsing integers from the groups that matched (if it did)?

Comment: As a general hint before asking questions on Stack Overflow, we typically link people to [this guide](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for looking for problems first. It's important to be able to understand *what parts of the code actually ran, and exactly what each part did* when something goes wrong. As a bonus for making a proper [mre], hard-code the input rather than showing a program that asks the user for inputs (unless the question is about getting that input).

Answer (score -2):

Check if `matches` is `None` *before* you start trying to treat it as an instance of `Match`.

```
def convert(s):
    matches = re.search(r"^([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)? (AM|PM) to ([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)? (AM|PM)$", s)

    if match is None:
        raise ValueError

    # Now you can assume matches is an instance of Match
    hour1 = int(matches.group(1))
    ...
```

Comment: Thank a lot chepner! this took me so many hours!
Thank you all for your help.